# systemjs auto load plugins after jquery

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I am trying to get a handle on systemjs, and understand how to load dependencies: ie load these scripts before this script loads, however I am stuck on doing the reverse...

I have a set of default jQuery plugins that I always want loaded after jQuery is loaded.  Is there a way to set this up in the systemjs config so that I always have my plugins loaded when jQuery is loaded?  These would need to be loaded after jQuery loads and not before.

Current systemjs config file

```
System.config({
//defaultJSExtensions: true,
//Create new header in WebExchange to load this beast..
baseUrl: WE_CONTEXT + '/assets',

map: {

    css: 'css.js',
    //Map JQuery
    'jquery': 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js',

    //Begin DataTables
    'dataTables': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
    'dataTablesCss': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css',
    'dataTablesButtonPlugin': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js',
    'dataTablesButtonBootstrapPlugin': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js',
    'dataTablesColSearchPlugin': 'plugins/datatables/datatables.colsearch.plugin.js',
    'dataTablesResponsivePlugin': 'plugins/datatables/dataTables.responsive.js',
    'dataTablesResponsiveCss': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css',
    'dataTablesButtonCss': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css'
    //End

},

meta: {
    '*.css': {loader: 'css'},

    'jQuery' : {

        'deps' : []
    },

    'dataTables': {
        //Dependecies to load before module i.e DataTables
        'deps': ['dataTablesCss', 'jquery', 'dataTablesColSearchPlugin', 'dataTablesResponsivePlugin', 'dataTablesResponsiveCss']
    },

    'dataTablesButtonPlugin': {

        'deps': ['dataTablesButtonBootstrapPlugin', 'dataTablesButtonCss']
    }
},
bundles: {
    'jquery': ['dataTables']
    //'datatablesCss' : ['dataTables']
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a construct with setTimout, like this:

```js
function waitJQuery () {

  if(!window.jQuery) {
    setTimeout(() => waitJQuery , 200);
  } else {
     execute();
  }

}

function execute () {
 // your code here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You check if JQuery is there, if not you execute the waitJQuery again.

Comment: is there a way to setup the systemjs config to handle this scenario?  I will modify my question to add the current config.